# Getting 404 for livewire/message/{component}

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I had [this](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/242) issue which was fixed by running `php artisan vendor:publish --force -tag=livewire:assets` but then when Livewire is trying to Hydrate, and post to livewire/message/MY_COMPONENT, it still gets a 404. This works fine locally with `php artisan serve`, but not with Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

late answer, but check if you have Apache `mod_rewrite` `enabled` or if using `nginx` you add in your `nginx.conf` file or `sitefile`.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be also solved by clearing route cache.
Use the command:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Cheers!